# Why was the value of pointer p changed when any value was assigned to *(p+1)?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int* p = NULL;
    int y = 1;
    p = &y;
    printf("%p\n",p);
    *(p+1) = 10;
    printf("%p\n",p);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs：

> 0x7ffe2368f2e4
>   0x7ffe0000000a

I do not know why p was changed here and the second one has "0000000a" which is 10 in the end, could you help me with that? thank you. I compiled it with gcc in linux.

Comment: Think about the meaning of **undefined** like in _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I just got confused about the memory allocation here, because I never changed the value of pointer p but p was changed, now I got the answer, you can have a look at the answer i accepted, and other answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two variables `y` and `p` are allocated on the stack. Their storage is adjacent to each other, and looks like this:

```
y: <addr1> <val1>  4 bytes
p: <addr2> <val2>  8 bytes
```

Note that `<addr2>` is `<addr1> + 4`.

For your example, the actual addresses look like this:

```
y: 0x00007ffe2368f2e4 <value1>  4 bytes
p: 0x00007ffe2368f2e8 <value2>  8 bytes
```

After `y = 1` and `p = &y`, the memory looks like follows:

```
y: 0x00007ffe2368f2e4 0x00000001          4 bytes
p: 0x00007ffe2368f2e8 0x00007ffe2368f2e4  8 bytes
```

`p + 1` is value of `p` + `sizeof(int)`, which is `0x00007ffe2368f2e4 + 4`, which is `0x00007ffe2368f2e8`, which is the address of `p`.

`*(p + 1) = 10` sets 4 bytes at `0x00007ffe2368f2e8` to `10`.

This is overwriting 4 bytes of a 8 byte value at `0x00007ffe2368f2e8`, which is 4 bytes of the value of `p`.

```
0x7ffe 2368f2e4
0x7ffe 0000000a ------> this is the lower 4 bytes set to 10 i.e. 0xa
```

Comment: This is very clear for me  to understand. This exactly explains why when I tried to change p+1 to p+3, the value of p remained the same. Thank you very much. Since it is my first question in stackoverflow, I do not have enough reputation to vote for you, thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

> *What cause the change of address the pointer points to?*

TL;DR - [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, in your code,

```
*(p+1) = 10;
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you try to access a a memory out of bound. Kindly note, segmentation fault in only *one of the many possible side-effects of UB*.

Once your code invokes UB, nothing, absolutely nothing is guaranteed.

Also, FWIW, to print a pointer, you should be casting the pointer to `void*` before using that as an argument to `%p`.

Comment: If segmentation fault was guaranteed to occur, it would be called **defined** behaviour.

Comment: It is not out of bound, p was allocated 8 bytes, and p+1 is within the 8 bytes because 1 only occupies 4 bytes.

Comment: @brickmanjim what??? `p was allocated 8 bytes, and p+1 is within the 8 bytes`..how exactly? It ___is___ out of bound access.

Comment: p and y are adjacent in a stack, in a 64-bit system, 8 bytes are allcated to int*, you can have a look at the accepted answer, there is a trick here you may not have noticed.

Comment: @brickmanjim I have seen that, but the catch here is, even that is not guaranteed. In _this_ case, the theory seems correct, but in general, compiler is free to chose the memory allocation in the exact opposite way possible. Just saying.

Comment: You mean that y and p may not contigous in a stack, right? As I know, when a process starts, cpu will allocate a contigous space for that process and the address range is stored in pcb, any other processes cannot access its space and this process also cannot access others', and the commands in a process are contigous in a stack, right? Do you mean the phisical addresses may not contigous like logical addresses?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this statement invokes undefined behavior:

```
*(p+1) = 10;
```

Since prior to this statement, `p` contains the address of `y`, which is of type `int`.  So the above statement writes to an area of memory which is not `y`.

As for an explanation of what actually happened, it appears that `p` appears right after `y` on the stack.  So when you do `*(p+1) = 10;`, it writes to the `sizeof(int)` bytes after `y` on the stack, which happens to be where `p` lives.

Based on the fact that the initial value of `p` is 0x7ffe2368f2e4, that tells us that `sizeof(int *)` is at least 6 bytes, most likely 8 (i.e. 64 bit).  With the value changing to 0x7ffe0000000a after the assignment, we see that the 4 low-order bytes of `p` were modified.  This would make sense if `sizeof(int)` is 4 and you're working in a little-endian architecture.  So the assignment ends up setting the first 4 bytes of `p` (the low order bytes) to the value `10` while leaving the rest (the high order bytes) unchanged.

That's what happened in your particular case.  There is no guarantee that this behavior will be consistent across different machines, compilers, or operating systems.  In other words, undefined behavior.

Comment: Please, can you explain in more details how to figure out `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(int *)` from addresses values.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan See my edit.  I hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
*(p+1) = 10;
```

changes the pointer because it overwrites the memory occupied by the pointer.

As you can see from the output values

```
0x7ffe2368f2e4 0x7ffe0000000a
```

this part `0x0000000a` of the value `0x7ffe0000000a` exactly equal to 10 that is assigned to the memory at address `p + 1`

So at the address `p + 1` there is the pointer p itself.

If the `sizeof( int )` is equal to 4 then `0x7ffe2368f2e4` is the address of `y` and `0x7ffe2368f2e8` is the address of the memory occupied by pointer p itself that is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about this is as y being like an array of 1 integer (that is only y[0] exists.  The code:

```
*(a+i)  equals  a[i]
```

by definition.  So, since:

```
p = &y
```

then:

```
*(p+1)  equals  y[1]
```

and accessing that which does not exist is undefined behavior.  That means anything can happen, but the two most likely things are (1) you access some other variable (what happened to you) or (2) the program gets a segmentation fault.